# How to read an encrypted database created previously on pc with sqlcipher on android?

Tags: android, sqlcipher

I'm trying to read an encrypted database created with sqlcipher on my PC but I can't read it on my app. For example:

```
Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'", null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    do {
        String s = c.getString(0);
        if (s.equals("android_metadata")) {
            // System.out.println("Get Metadata");
            continue;
        } else {
            dirArray.add(s);
        }
    } while (c.moveToNext());
    Log.i("getS", "DATABASE = " + dirArray.toString());
    Log.i("getS", "length = " + dirArray.size());
```

result on the following

```
03-12 03:28:12.691: I/getS(9895): DATABASE = []
03-12 03:28:12.691: I/getS(9895): length = 0
```

also this:

```
Cursor c2 = database.query("my_table", new String[] { "name" }, null, null, null, null, "name");
```

return in to this:

```
03-12 03:28:12.701: I/Database(9895): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: my_table
```

I'm compiling with sdk-7, if I try the same database unencrypted and without the sqlcipher, I don't have any problems.
Could anyone teach me how do I read on android a database encrypted on my computer?
Appreciate ;)

Comment: I ran into a similar issue and received a solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742686/sqlcipher-sharing-a-windows-created-database-with-an-android-application

Comment: @djx- were you able to solve the problem ?? i would really apprecaite any help ! thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use the SQLCipher for Android library which will allow you to access and modify a sqlcipher database on an Android device.  We currently support Android 2.1 - 4.0.3.  Binary downloads can be found here:

https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher/downloads

A tutorial on itegrating SQLCipher for Android can be found here:

http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-for-android/

Comment: I already add the libraries like it's on tutorial, but still doesn't work.

Comment: Also, that tutorial doesn't teach how to read a database created from PC

Comment: @djx- were you able to solve the problem ?? i would really apprecaite any help ! thanks

Comment: @nia - Sorry but no, since then I was waiting if anyone had any example or something like that. If you get any progress please tell me.

Comment: @aanm I'm facing it now too... Did you solve the probem? I'm stuck and unable to get any help...